# Allure Framework: TestNG adapter generates duplicate XML files

Tags: java, maven, testng, allure

I am trying to use Allure with TestNG and Maven using this [example](https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example). Each time I run this example duplicate copies of xml files are generated. I am using allure 1.4.0.RC8. Any guidance on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Allure 1.4.0.RC4 listener adds via ServiceLoader. Just remove listener property from maven-surefire-plugin. This configuration should work:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <configuration>
            <argLine>
                -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
            </argLine>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Read more at our wiki: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/TestNG

Comment: Yes It worked.I had removed the Allure listener from the POM.xml and test Class files